# Remove ink from coroplast

Tags: cleaning, plastics, paint, chemicals, recycling

I'm trying to remove the ink/paint from coroplast signs with a simple trick. Any household item, something not too expensive that I can find easily. I saw once that recycling facilities could remove it so maybe I can do it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type of ink.

Some inks are soluble in alcohols, e.g. ethanol or  isopropanol (use at least 70% or stronger to try to remove the ink).

Some inks are soluble in non-polar solvents, such as vegetable oil or paint thinner (flammable).

Some inks can be removed with aromatic solvents, such as xylene and toluene, but though one can purchase them in hardware stores as varnish thinner, they are [somewhat more hazardous to use](http://www.dow.com/webapps/lit/litorder.asp?filepath=productsafety/pdfs/noreg/233-00945.pdf&pdf=true) and are [likely to attack the Coroplast [polypropylene] substrate](http://www.coroplast.com/technicalinfo/resistance.htm).

So, depending on the the ink formulation, test the three types of solvent, above. Be aware that some ink dyes can soak into polypropylene and may be difficult to remove.

Comment: I tried isopropanol (rubbing alcohol) at 70% and it worked well. At first you need to rub really hard then it comes off easily.

Answer (score 0):

**Using an All Purpose Cleaner and Ammonia**

You Will Need:

1. All purpose cleaner
2. Ammonia
3. Water
4. Mild soap
5. Soft cloths
6. Cotton balls

Steps to Remove the Ink:

1. Spray the ink stained [coroplast](https://corrugatedplasticsheet.net/) with an all purpose cleaner.
2. Wipe away with a clean cloth.
3. If the stain remains, moisten a soft cloth or cotton ball with
   ammonia.
4. Lay it on the ink stain for a few minutes, then wipe away.
5. Wash the area with soapy water to remove any cleaning residue.
6. Dry with a soft cloth.

**Using Rubbing Alcohol**

You Will Need:

1. Rubbing alcohol
2. Soft cloths
3. Cotton balls

Steps to Remove the Ink:

1. Rubbing alcohol is effective in removing many ink stains without
   damaging the surface.
2. Moisten a cotton ball or soft cloth with the rubbing alcohol.
3. Rub it over the surface of the stain until the ink is removed. There
   is no need to apply excessive pressure, just continual rubbing will
   remove the ink.
4. Once removed, dry with a soft cloth.